# で vs が in 上手に話せます？

Tags: particle-が, particle-で, potential-form

> 日本語**で**上手に話せます。
>
> 日本語**が**上手にはなせます。

Hello, I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but is it で or が? I know you're supposed to use で for languages, but this sentence I got from class is using が。

I'm utterly confused :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, the particle で denotes method/means ('by means of', 'with', 'using', etc.) The difference is 'speak *in* Japanese' vs 'speak Japanese'.

> - 日本語**で**上手に話せます。
>     One can (speak / talk with someone / say something) well **in** Japanese.
> - 日本語**が**上手に話せます。
>     One can speak Japanese well. (= One is a good Japanese speaker).

When someone says 日本語で話す, it means talking with someone, or saying something, *using / by means of Japanese*. The speaker usually has some concrete objective in their mind, and is concerned about whether or not one can [do it / say it / talk with them] well *in* Japanese.

For example, this sentence is OK:

> - 明日の講演は、日本語で上手に話せると思います。
>     (literally) As for tomorrow's lecture, I think I can speak well *in* Japanese.

However, when you're talking about whether or not someone is a good Japanese speaker in general, 日本語が上手に話せる is much more natural.

Comment: Thank you so much. These slight nuances in the language is killing me.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of two sentences is same. で in this case is used as the method of representing tool and が is used as a postpositional particle of the method of representing the subject.

Comment: Hi thank you for replying. So, you're saying that they're the same so I could either use で or が, and it shouldn't matter?

Comment: Yes、 you can use the both sentences.